# Redirect function are not working while doing login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller:

```
public function home()
{
    $data['admin_id'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
    print_r($data['admin_id']);
}
```

view:

```
<?php
    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    { 
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->db->select('username,password');
        $this->db->from('admin');
        $where = "username='$username' and password = '$password'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $num = $query->num_rows();
        if($num > 0)
        {
            $this->db->select('username,password,admin_id');
            $this->db->from('admin');
            $where = "username='$username' and password = '$password'";
            $this->db->where($where);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result_array();
            $this->session->set_userdata('admin_id',$result);
            if($result == true)
            {
                redirect('home');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p style='color: red;font-weight: 400;margin-right: 60px;'>Wrong email id or password! </p>";
        }
    }
?>
<form class="form-signin" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

In this code I have create a simple login page where I have to use redirect function i.e. redirect('home'). it does not working on live I dont't know why but it working on localhost and inside the controller I have also session id i.e. admin_id and I also use print_r function to print the value of admin_id but it also not working yet. So, How can I fix this issue? Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: hope u have added url helper,any error

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

**Please check autoload.php file**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

I u can try :

```
<?php
if($this->input->post('submit'))
{ 
    $username = $this->input->post('username',true);
    $password = $this->input->post('password',true);
    $q = $this->db->query("select username,password,admin_id from admin where username ? and password = ?",$array($username,$password));
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        $out = $q->result();
        $out = $out[0]
    } else {
        //Error here
        $out = FALSE;
    }
    if($out !== FALSE){
        $this->session->set_userdata('admin_id',$out->admin_id);
            redirect(base_url('home'));
            die();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p style='color: red;font-weight: 400;margin-right: 60px;'>Wrong email id or password! </p>";
    }
}
```

?>

and in application/config/autoload => insert url in helper array.
 `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

and in your config.php u can set $congif['base_url']